# Best way test for XPath existence in an XML file?

Tags: c#, xml

Lately I've been using XPathDocument and XNavigator to parse an XML file for a given XPath and attribute. It's been working very well, when I know in advance what the XPath is.

Sometimes though, the XPath will be one of several possible XPath values, and I'd like to be able to test whether or not a given XPath exists.

In case I'm getting the nomenclature wrong, here's what I'm calling an XPath - given this XML blob:

```
<foo>
    <bar baz="This is the value of the attribute named baz">
</foo>
```

I might be looking for what I'm calling an XPath of "//foo/bar" and then reading the attribute "baz" to get the value.

Example of the code that I use to do this:

```
XPathDocument document = new XPathDocument(filename);
XPathNavigator navigator = document.CreateNavigator();
XPathNavigator node = navigator.SelectSingleNode("//foo/bar");
if(node.HasAttributes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(node.GetAttribute("baz", string.Empty));
}
```

Now, if the call to navigator.SelectSingleNode fails, it will return a NullReferenceException or an XPathException. I can catch both of those and refactor the above into a test to see whether or not a given XPath returns an exception, but I was wondering whether there was a better way?

I didn't see anything obvious in the Intellisense. XPathNavigator has .HasAttributes and .HasChildren but short of iterating through the path one node at a time, I don't see anything nicer to use.

Comment: What does this have to do with LINQ? XPathNavigator and XPathDocument aren't part of LINQ to XML.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you've given valid XPath but it doesn't match anything, `SelectSingleNode` won't *throw* a `NullReferenceException` - it will just return null.

If you pass `SelectSingleNode` some syntactically invalid XPath, that's when it will throw  an `XPathException`.

So normally, you'd just need to test whether the returned value was null or not.

Answer (score 1):

```
 var baz = navigator.SelectSingleNode("//foo/bar/@baz");
 if (baz != null) Console.WriteLine(baz);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not good to create an XMLNode object by executing navigator.SelectSingleNode(...).

You have to use navigator.Evaluate() instead:

```
if (Convert.ToBoolean(navigator.Evaluate(@"boolean(//foo/bar)"))) {...}
```

Comment: I did a speed comparison of this method compared to SelectSingleNode, for 500,000 iterations each (with the XPath expression as a string, uncompiled).  The SelectSingleNode method was 16-18% faster than the boolean method.  I've repeated the test several times and the results are consistent.

Answer (score 0):

From memory, may contain errors.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("foo.xml");

var att = from a in doc.Descendants("bar")
          select a.Attribute("baz")

foreach (var item in att) {
    if (item != null) { ... }
}
```

Comment: Since the question title mentions Linq, here's how I would do it.

Comment: Use .FirstOrDefault on the query if you want just one

Answer (score 0):

If `node == null` then `node.HasAttributes` will throw a `NullReferenceException`. This situation will occur when `//foo/bar` does not match any elements in the XML document.

Answer (score 0):

```
var node = XDocument.Load(filename)
                    .Descendants("bar")
                    .SingleOrDefault(e=>e.Attribute("baz") != null);

if (node != null) Console.WriteLine(node.Attribute("baz").Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably be more specific in my xpath.

```
        var doc = XDocument.Load(fileName);

        var results = from r in doc.XPathSelectElements("/foo/bar[count(@baz) > 0]")
                      select r.Attribute("baz");

        foreach (String s in results)
            Console.WriteLine(s);
```